# How to fix "TypeError: object of type 'CategoricalDtype' has no len()" problem in the fit() method?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

I am trying out Titanic dataset on Kaggle. I used dropna() to keep it simple and also dropped a couple of columns. However, I get the "TypeError: object of type 'CategoricalDtype' has no len()" message when I call the fit() method.

I have tried to use different classifiers, but I get the same error. I guess there is something amiss in my data preparation.

````py
    df = pd.read_csv('train.csv')
    df.drop('PassengerId', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.drop('Ticket', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.drop('Cabin', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df.drop('Embarked', axis=1, inplace=True)
    df=df.dropna()
    mapping = {'male': 0, 'female': 1}
    df = df.replace({'Sex': mapping})
    paramlist=['Pclass', 'Sex', 'Age', 'SibSp', 'Parch', 'Fare']
    X, y = df[paramlist], df.Survived.astype('category')
    X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=42)
    classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = classifier.predict(X_test)
    confusion_table = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)

print("KNN regression using: "+ str(paramlist))
print(confusion_table)
print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred))
print(f"Accuracy: {accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)}")
print("=======================================")


```python

Error trace -
  File "<ipython-input-2-e6618b2ba888>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/vvnat/Documents/Vaibhav/Dropbox/Kaggle/Titanic/Titanic.py', wdir='C:/Users/vvnat/Documents/Vaibhav/Dropbox/Kaggle/Titanic')

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/vvnat/Documents/Vaibhav/Dropbox/Kaggle/Titanic/Titanic.py", line 222, in <module>
    classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py", line 891, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, "csr", multi_output=True)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 759, in check_X_y
    dtype=None)

  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 480, in check_array
    if hasattr(array, "dtypes") and len(array.dtypes):

TypeError: object of type 'CategoricalDtype' has no len()
````

Answer (score 1):

try to make X and y np.arrays, id est X = np.array(X) and y = np.array(y), just before train_test_split()

Answer (score 1):

this error means the dtype of some columns in your dataframe is 'category', so you should first use df.info to check the dtype of each columns, then try to check the suitable dtype of each column and use astype() to change the dtype of the error column such as 'np.int64' or 'np.float64'. good luck